# Chrome extension: How to add an option on the right click menu of an HTML element using manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to create a Chrome extension to get the background image of an HTML element so I added an option in the right-click menu. It worked in Manifest v2 but when I tried to update to Manifest v3 my code did not longer worked.
Is there a thing I missed?

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "description": "Get background image of an HTML element",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "BackgroundImage get",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "homepage_url": "https://www.example.com",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon48.png"
  },
  
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus"
  ],

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "32": "icons/icon32.png",
      "48": "icons/icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    }
  }

}
```

And here is my `background.js` file:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Get Background Image',
    onclick: function(e){
        console.log("Example action")
    }
}, function(){})
```

I tried to edit my `manifest.json` like that:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "BackgroundImage get",
    "description": "Get background image of an HTML element",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "32": "icons/icon32.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Background Image",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the error output in DevTools of Service Worker.

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Extensions using event pages or Service Workers must pass an id parameter to chrome.contextMenus.create

Fixing this error prints the following error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Extensions using event pages or Service Workers cannot pass an onclick parameter to chrome.contextMenus.create. Instead, use the chrome.contextMenus.onClicked event.

Fix this error and your extension will work correctly.

background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'hoge',
    title: 'Get Background Image',
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info) => {
  console.log("Example action")
});
```